# Get RGB pixels from input image and reconstruct an output image in opencv

Tags: image, opencv, rgb

I want to load the image in opencv and split the image into channels(RGB) and i want to increase any one of the colors and getting that corresponding output image.is there any easiest way to do this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well to add any scalar to an RGB image you can use cvAddS(srcImage, scalarToAdd, dstImage).
Here is an example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

{
// Create a named window with the name of the file.
cvNamedWindow( argv[1], 1 );
// Load the image from the given file name.
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
//Make a scalar to add 30 to Blue Color and 20 to Red (BGR format)
CvScalar colorAdd = cvScalar(30.0, 0, 20.0);
cvAddS(img, colorAdd, img);
// Show the image in the named window
cvShowImage( argv[1], img );
// Idle until the user hits the “Esc” key.
while( 1 ) {
if( cvWaitKey( 100 ) == 27 ) break;
}
cvDestroyWindow( argv[1] );
cvReleaseImage( &img );
exit(0);
}
```

Haven't tested the code, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

@karlphillip: Generally a better solution for RGB images - handles any padding at row ends, also parallelizes nicely with OMP !

```
for (int i=0; i < height;i++) 
{
    unsigned char *pRow = pRGBImg->ptr(i);
    for (int j=0; j < width;j+=bpp) 
    // For educational puporses, here is how to print each R G B channel:
      std::cout << std::dec << "R:" << (int) pRow->imageData[j] <<  
                          " G:" << (int) pRow->imageData[j+1] <<  
                          " B:" << (int) pRow->imageData[j+2] << " "; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the OpenCV C++ interface you can simply add a Scalar to an image with the overloaded arithmetic operators.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cv::Mat image;
    // read an image
    if (argc < 2)
        return 2;

    image = cv::imread(argv[1]);

    if (!image.data) {
        std::cout << "Image file not found\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cv::Mat image2 = image.clone(); // Make a deep copy of the image
    image2 += cv::Scalar(30,0,20); // Add 30 to blue, 20 to red

    cv::namedWindow("original");
    cv::imshow("original", image);

    cv::namedWindow("addcolors");
    cv::imshow("addcolors", image2);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to **manually iterate on the pixels** of the image and work on the channel that interests you. This will give you the flexibility to manipulate each channel individually or as a group.

The following code uses the C interface of OpenCV:

```
IplImage* pRGBImg = cvLoadImage("test.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); 
int width = pRGBImg->width; 
int height = pRGBImg->height;
int bpp = pRGBImg->nChannels; 
for (int i=0; i < width*height*bpp; i+=bpp) 
{
  // For educational puporses, here is how to print each R G B channel:
  std::cout << std::dec << "R:" << (int) pRGBImg->imageData[i] <<  
                          " G:" << (int) pRGBImg->imageData[i+1] <<  
                          " B:" << (int) pRGBImg->imageData[i+2] << " "; 
}
```

However, if you want to add a fixed value to a certain channel you might want to check @Popovici's answer.